# Mongos unable to find document after migration

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have set up a mongo cluster as follows:

- Four shards => `mongoshard1 (Disk1)`, `mongoshard2 (Disk2)`, `mongoshard3(Disk3)`, `mongoshard4(Disk4)`
- Replica set of one configuration server => `mongoshardconfig (Disk5)`
- One mongos server => `mongos`
- Shard key is a hashed index of `_id`

The entire setup is on a single server and the various mongod instances have been setup on different ports. (Setting up on a single server instead of different nodes has been a conscious decision though against recommended practices)

My server got terminated and I created a new cluster on another server with exact same settings as above using the old disks. The sharded collection document has a field: `url` . For a particular id, if I search using `_id`, mongos returns null but returns the object on finding using the `url`. Connecting individually to shard2 returns the object on querying using same `_id`. Some of the documents are found by querying on `_id` through mongos and some are not.

Why is mongos unable to find the document using id? Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When querying with _id thru mongos, system directs that query to right node using config -databases chunks -collection information. It sounds like that "order" of your shards has been changed. (meaning that disk1 is not anymore at mongoshard1 -machine). Connect shard directly  and

`use local
db.me.find()`

to check that nodes are who they should be.

Comment: That exactly was the problem. Correcting the order solved the problem for us. Thank you!

Comment: Is there an alternative for the recovery process other than the way mentioned in the question?

Comment: Moving all chunks to one shard (and then let balancer 're-balance' data back to other shards OR Dumping all data out, re-creating cluster and import data back.